# How to check if button is read Only or enabled in Selenium Using Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to find the button whether it is Read Only or Enabled (Clickable) in the page. After doing some action. I need to check this in if else condition so kindly help me to find the solution.

below are my html code of the button

#### When the Button is Read Only

```
<div id="agent_delete" 
     class="btn btn_own" 
     ng-confirm-click="Are you sure you want to delete selected Agent(s)?" 
     confirm-click-title="Delete Agent" 
     confirmed-click="delete()" 
     ng-disabled="!ctrlService.canDelete || gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().length == 0" 
     disabled="disabled">
```

#### When the button is Enabled or clickable

```
<div id="agent_delete" 
     class="btn btn_own" 
     ng-confirm-click="Are you sure you want to delete selected Agent(s)?" 
     confirm-click-title="Delete Agent" 
     confirmed-click="delete()" 
     ng-disabled="!ctrlService.canDelete || gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().length == 0">
```

Comment: I tried using driver.findElement(By.id("agent_delete")).getAttribute("disabled").equals(true) in if condition

Comment: Then I tried using driver.findElement(By.id("agent_delete")).is_Enabled(True). but both are not working.

Comment: Even i tried using Xpath -- //div[contains(@disabled,'disabled')] with IsEnabled function

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **isEnabled();** method.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("agent_delete")).isEnabled()){
   //button is enabled
}
else{
//button is not enabled
}
```

Comment: No i have already tried this. What ever the button status, it is passing through the True Condition that is "Button Enabled" condition

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `disabled` attribute with `getAttribute`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("agent_delete"));
if("disabled".equals(element.getAttribute("disabled"))) {
  // disabled
} else {
  // enabled
}
```

Or with a CSS selector with a single call:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#agent_delete[disabled='disabled']")).size > 0) {
  // disabled
} else {
  // enabled
}
```

Comment: No @florent both the solution is not working what ever the button status is, it goes into the Enabled Condition that is else part.

Comment: If you are always getting the else statement, then the element is not disabled at that at the time you are executing the code. You probably need to wait for a state or element before checking the disable state. But without a reproducible example, there's nothing much I can do to help.

Comment: But for ur understanding the button will be in read only state(Not completely disabled from the screen). If i select any record then the Read only button will become enabled or clickable.